# Escape sequence in C in string

Tags: c, escaping, comments, string-literals

In this code:

```
int main() 
{ 
   char str[]= "geeks\nforgeeks"; 
   char *ptr1, *ptr2; 
       
   ptr1 = &str[3]; 
   ptr2 = str + 5; 
   printf("%c", ++*str - --*ptr1 + *ptr2 + 2);  
   printf("%s", str);  
   
   getchar(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Why does the compiler interpret \n as an escape sequence and not as two characters viz, \ and n?

On the other hand, this program does not comment out hello.

```
int main() 
{ 
   char str[]= "geeks/*hello*/geeks";
   printf ("%s",str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `\n` is defined to be an escape sequence?

Comment: But that is inside a string, so how does the compiler know?

Comment: As a counter argument

Comment: @programmer \ is not the same as /. \ is treated specially.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You are not clear can you please put in the answer

Comment: Inside a string literal / is just a normal character but \ is an escape character so that un printable characters such as line feed, tabs, carriage returns etc can be written. See answers below.

Comment: If it wasn't inside a string, there would not escape character be needed at all.

Comment: Where did you expect to find escape sequences if not inside strings?

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the compiler interpret \n as an escape sequence and not as
> two characters viz, \ and n?

By the definition of the escape sequence.

The C Standard (5.2.2 Character display semantics)

> 2 Alphabetic escape sequences representing nongraphic characters in
> the execution character set are intended to produce actions on display
> devices as follows:
>
> //...
> \n (new line) Moves the active position to the initial position
> of the next line.

If you want to have two separate characters `\` and `n` then you should write for example

```
char str[]= "geeks\\nforgeeks";
```

Now there are two separate characters one of which is represented by the escape sequence `'\\'` and other by the symbol `'n'`.

As for the second your question

> On the other hand, this program does not comment out hello.

```
char str[]= "geeks/*hello*/geeks";
```

Then within a string literal symbols /* and */ do not form a comment. They are elements of the string literal.

The C Standard (6.4.9 Comments)

> 1 **Except within a character constant, a string literal**, or a
> comment, the characters /* introduce a comment. The contents of such a
> comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find
> the characters */ that terminate it.

Answer (score 2):

> But that is inside a string, so how does the compiler know?

The below quotes and links are sufficient enough to understand what is an escape sequence.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

> In C, all escape sequences consist of two or more characters, the first of which is the backslash, \ (called the "Escape character");

Also from [C11 Standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.4)

> In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by escape sequences consisting of the backslash \ followed by one or more characters. A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.